# A town E miles away?

Tags: mathematics

[image]

I got this from my maths teacher

> **What is the value of 'E'?**

Comment: Where did you get this puzzle from? If you didn't create it yourself, you need to give credit to the source, otherwise it will probably be deleted. [Edit] it in, if needed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> E=76. (fist letter, last letter, A1Z26, so G=7, F=6).

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Seems to be fully valid and plausible answer...